# .click function .load not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a total novice at jQuery, but giving it a go. I cant seem to get the `.click` function below to work.  Can anyone tell me were I am going wrong?

```
$(".news").click(function() {
    $("#contentarea").load("console/news.php");
});
```

Comment: It should work fine, although you don't give a definition of what "work" means. Make sure an element with the `new` class exists, and that it wasn't dynamically generated.

Comment: works on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z5AUX/1/

Comment: in case you are creating the element dinamically, use .live() (now deprecated) or .on()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run the code in the `ready` event, so that the news element(s) are loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".news").click(function() {
    $("#contentarea").load("console/news.php");
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

wrap the code inside the ready handler

```
$(function(){
 //your code
});
```

or you can put the javascript code at the end of the markup like

```
//your html

<script>

//js code here
</script>
```